# Periodically consume data from http service using Observable in Angular 2 / 4

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, typescript2.0, angular2-observables

I'm learning to use angular (4) for the front end to my REST api backend.

I currently have a PostList Component which displays a list of posts. Im using an returning an Observable> in my daoService, and subsribing to this in the onInit inside my PostListComponent. 
This all works fine and im fairly happy with it, however i'd like to use something like interval to automatically make this call every, say, 5 secconds.
Ive tried initially to follow some similar pattern as seen in the official angular site at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#sts=Observables , however the use case is different enough and the structure of my project is ifferent enough that I had real problems following it in a useful way and eventually gave up. I have google around quite alot and am struggling to find a straightforward way of how i can periodically consume data from my api using the observer/subscriber pattern with some interval.

Any suggestion on how i can adapt the following code to make the call at intervals would be very useful to me, and i imagine, lots of other devs new to angular.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Post} from '../class/post';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class PostDaoService      {

  private jwt: String;

  private commentsUrl = 'http://MYDOMAIN/posts';

  constructor(private http: Http, private opt: RequestOptions) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    this.jwt = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJQYXNjYNFHUHSFWQiOiIxMjMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4ifQ.4D9TUDQAgIWAooyiMN1lV8Y5wVCrIF4rAeGzFzelSE9diqHMik9WE9x4EsNnEcxQXYATjxAZovpp-m72LpFADA';
   }

  getPosts(): Observable<Array<Post>> {
    this.opt.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.jwt);
    this.opt.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(this.commentsUrl)
      .map((response) => response.json())
      .map((data: any) => {
        return data._embedded.posts as Post[];
      });
  }
}

import { ContextMenuService } from '../../../baseui-module/context-menu/context-menu.service';

import { Post } from '../../class/post';
import { PostDaoService } from '../../service/post-dao.service';
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[];

  constructor(public service: ContextMenuService, public dao: PostDaoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.postItems();
    this.dao.getPosts().subscribe((data: Array<Post>) => {
      this.posts = data;
    });
  }

  public getItems(): Post[] {
    return this.posts;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a `mergeMap`/`flatMap` (depending on your rxjs version):

```
getPosts(trigger: Observable<any>): Observable<Array<Post>> {
  this.opt.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.jwt);
  this.opt.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return trigger.flatMap(() =>
     this.http.get(this.commentsUrl)
      .map((response) => response.json())
      .map((data: any) => {
        return data._embedded.posts as Post[];
      });
}
```

And then in your component:

```
this.dao.getPosts(Observable.timerInterval(0, 5000)
   .subscribe(data => ....);
```

Obviously you can use it with other triggers:

```
this.dao.getPosts(Observable.fromEvent(refreshButton, 'click'))
```

To refresh when the refresh button is clicked

Btw, you might want to avoid the subscribe and instead define:

```
this.posts$ = this.dao.getPosts(...);
```

and in your template:

```
<any *ngFor="let post of posts$">post display here</any>
```

This will be more efficient and reduce the risk of dangling subscribers and memory leaks.

Comment: unfortunately timerInterval(n, m) is not available in Observable, so I changed to interval(5000) which fixed the compile error, however I now get the following error: core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.interval is not a function
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.interval is not a function

Comment: Did you add an import? I think it is import 'rxjs/observable/add/interval'

Comment: I just imported that explicitly and now it says that flatMap (or mergeMap) is not a function. tried importing these explicitly but go nowhere. Edit: also, if i temporarily swap trigger variable for Observable object with . so that i can inspect the api, neither of these functions are available

Comment: It depends on the version of rxjs. Have a look for it on SO and see what needs to be done, for example: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8167

Comment: it turns out that a lot of my problem was that my IDE was not importing some things in the correct way. Also my IDE would have no problem with providing intelligent code suggestions for functions of Observable (for example) with no errors, but actually making them available to angular at runtime required a separate explicit import. Thanks for all your help. sorted now.